# Why am I not able to access variable from react context? Can you identify the mistake?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-context

I wanna access an array called "currentNode" from the react context, but looks like it does not work. The console error message is the following:

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property '0' of null.

It seems that I cannot access the currentNode variable from the context.
Can you identify the mistake? Help is very much appreciated.

Step 1: Here is the code, how I dispatch it to the context:

```
const AuthState = (props) => {
  // auth state: create initial authState
  const initialState = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    chatId: null,
    currentNode: [],
  };

const fetchCurrentNode = async (chatId) => {
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "x-auth-token": "",
        },
      };

      const res1 = await axios.get(
        `http://localhost:4001/api/chatbots/${chatId}/nodeid`,
        //`https://mybot.uber.space/api/chatbots/${chatid}`
        //`https://sandbox.as.wiwi.uni-goettingen.de/teachr/chatbots/pin/${pin}`
        config
      );
      
      dispatch({
        type: NEW_CURRENT_NODE_CREATED,
        payload: currentNode,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

return (
    <ChatContext.Provider
      value={{
        chatId: state.chatId,
        chat: state.chat,
        chatSessionId: state.chatSessionId,
        createChatSessionId,
        addBackendAnswerToChat,
        addUserInputToChat,
        resetChat,
        fetchEventAnswerFromDialogflow,
        fetchAnswerFromDialogflow,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </ChatContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Step 1b: Here is my context declaration:

```
import React from 'react';

const chatContext = React.createContext();

export default chatContext;
```

Step 2: Here is how I saved it as Types:

```
export const NEW_CURRENT_NODE_CREATED = "NEW_CURRENT_NODE_CREATED";
```

Step 3: Here is my reducer function:

```
 import { CHATID_FETCH_SUCCESSFUL, NEW_CURRENT_NODE_CREATED } from "./authTypes";
    
    export default (state, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case NEW_CURRENT_NODE_CREATED:
          return {
            ...state,
            isAuthenticated: true,
            currentNode: [action.payload],
          };
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };
```

Step 4: And here is how I wanna get access to the currentNode variable:

```
 import AuthContext from "../../Context/Auth/authContext";

const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { chatId, currentNode } = authContext;

  console.log(chatId);
  console.log(currentNode);
```

Comment: where is your context declaration and provider usage?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, I added it above

Comment: I can't see where you update the `currentNode`, or where  the `res1` from axios is used?.

Comment: I don't see `currentNode` being passed in the value for your provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't add value you are trying to use to the context value

```
return (
    <ChatContext.Provider
      value={{
        chatId: state.chatId,
        chat: state.chat,
        currentNode: state.currentNode, // <-- ADD THIS LINE
        chatSessionId: state.chatSessionId,
        createChatSessionId,
        addBackendAnswerToChat,
        addUserInputToChat,
        resetChat,
        fetchEventAnswerFromDialogflow,
        fetchAnswerFromDialogflow,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </ChatContext.Provider>
  );
};
```